# Как React Router грузит модули? Можно ли сделать полосу загрузки?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, react-router-dom

Я навичок в React и хотелось бы знать как React Router грузит компоненты и можно ли сделать полосу состояния загрузки? Если да, то как?

Насколько я понимаю React Router грузит html страницы с Frontend сервера, а значит можно сделать прелоадер.

Возможно это не так и при открытии страницы все модули уже загружены и он просто их меняет?

Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно при помощи lazy loading:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const Drums = lazy(() => import('./components/Drums'));  // import
const Draw = lazy(() => import('./components/Draw'));    // import

const App = () => {        
  return (
    <div>
     <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Header} />       
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}>   {/* Lazy Loading Spinner */}        
        <Route path="/drums" component={Drums} />
        <Route path="/draw" component={Draw} />
        <Redirect to="/" />  
      </Suspense>
     </Router>
    <div>
   )
 }
```

без lazy loding всё грузится сразу.

Comment: Нельзя как-нибудь получить состояние в процентах?

Comment: lazy  в работе использует JS промисы которые могут быть resolved или rejected, прогресс в процентах не поддерживается

Comment: Как же тогда сервисы типа Github, YouTube делают полосу загрузки вверху?

Comment: можно отображать такую полосу без проблем но чтобы это были реальные проценты нужно специально писать под это backend

Comment: А без бека можно например сделать полосу которая просто будет медленно идти а когда всё загрузилось быстро доходить до конца? Но для этого нужно отслеживать конец операции

Comment: что то похожее есть в библиотеке material-ui.   https://material-ui.com/components/progress/